# Disable Enable Submit button - Disable until all fields have values - HTML form check all inputs for answers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to disable my submit button until all the fields have values. How can I do that? In form I have a select, file, datepicker and text inputs..

I have these examples but I could not make it work.

[Https://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/485/](http://Https://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/485/)

[Http://jsfiddle.net/Yr59d/](http://Http://jsfiddle.net/Yr59d/)

[Http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/6/](http://Http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/6/)

HTML:

```
    <form class="myForm" id="form">
         <div  id= "select_input" name="select1">
            <select name="select1">
               <option disabled selected>Unidade:</option>
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <span class="gbp">
            <input id= "value_input" name="value" type="number" min="0" max="10000" step="0.05" /><br/>
            <label> value:</label>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <label for="date">date</label>
            <input id="date_input" class="datepicker"  name="date" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <input id="email_input" name="email" type="email" /><br/>
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field ">
            <textarea id= "text_input" name="text" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="500"></textarea>
            <label for="text">Long Text.</label>
         </div>
      <div class="file-field input-field">
         <div class="btn">
            <span>File</span>
            <input id= "myFile_input" name="myFile" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="camera" >
         </div>
         <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text" >
         </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" value="Upload" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submit" onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress'); google.script.run .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput) .processForm(this.parentNode)">Submit </button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple parts to disabling / enabling the save button:

- Run code whenever a question is answered
- Disable / Enable Save button

Code Needed:

- Add Event handler to every question
- Check the answer of every question
- Disable / Enable Save button - add/remove the `disabled` attribute of the button:

HTML:

In the HTML, `onchange="areAllQuestionsAnswered()"` was added. That needs to be put into every question.

```
<form>
  <div  id= "select_input" name="select1">
    <select name="select1" onchange="areAllQuestionsAnswered()" required>
      <option disabled selected>Unidade:</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <div class="input-field ">
     <textarea id= "text_input" name="text" class="materialize-textarea"
       data-length="500" onchange="areAllQuestionsAnswered()"></textarea>
     <label for="text">Long Text.</label>
   </div>

   <div class="input-field">
     <span class="gbp">
       <input id= "value_input" name="value" type="number" min="0"
       max="10000" step="0.05" onchange="areAllQuestionsAnswered()" required><br/>
       <label> value:</label>
     </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Code:

```
<script>
  window.areAllQuestionsAnswered = function() {
    var allInputs,allDropDowns,allTextArea,
    arrayOfQuestions,i,j,L,L2,
    questionType,theseQuestions,
    thisQuestion,thisQstnType,thisValue;

    allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    allDropDowns = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
    allTextArea = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA");

    arrayOfQuestions = [allInputs,allDropDowns,allTextArea];

    L = arrayOfQuestions.length;

    for (i=0;i<L;i++) {

      theseQuestions = arrayOfQuestions[i];

      L2 = theseQuestions.length;

      for (j=0;j<L2;j++) {
        thisQuestion = theseQuestions[j];
        thisQstnType = thisQuestion.type;

        if (thisQstnType === 'checkbox') {
          thisValue = thisQuestion.checked;
        } else {
          thisValue = thisQuestion.value;
        }

        if (!thisValue) {
          enableOrDisableSave(false);
          return;//Quit - one of the questions was not answered
        }
      }
    }

    enableOrDisableSave(true);//If the code gets here then all questions
        //were answered
  }

  window.enableOrDisableSave = function(enable) {
    var saveBtn;

    saveBtn = document.getElementById('put submit button id here');

    if (enable) {
      saveBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');//Enable the save button by removing the disable setting
    } else {
      saveBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');//Disable the save button by
  //setting the attribute
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand how to use it. Can you give me an example? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you!! The textarea field does not work in this case. I tried:

`AllInputs = document.getElementsByTagName ("INPUT", "TEXTAREA");`
It did not work, either. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged html5, you can take the advantage of html5 validation using `required` attribute and changing submit button type to `type="submit"`

```
<form class="myForm" id="form" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
         <div  id= "select_input" name="select1">
            <select name="select1" required>
               <option disabled selected>Unidade:</option>
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <span class="gbp">
            <input id= "value_input" name="value" type="number" min="0" max="10000" step="0.05" required><br/>
            <label> value:</label>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <label for="date">date</label>
            <input id="date_input" class="datepicker"  name="date" type="text" required>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field">
            <input id="email_input" name="email" type="email" required><br/>
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field ">
            <textarea id= "text_input" name="text" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="500" required></textarea>
            <label for="text">Long Text.</label>
         </div>
      <div class="file-field input-field">
         <div class="btn">
            <span>File</span>
            <input id= "myFile_input" name="myFile" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="camera" required>
         </div>
         <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text" required>
         </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn waves-effect waves-light"  id="submit">Submit </button>
   </form>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        toggle_visibility('formDiv');
        toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput).processForm(this.parentNode);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi im my real form o button is:
`<button type="button" value="Upload" class="btn waves-effect waves-light"  id="submit" 
                           onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
                           google.script.run
                           .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
                           .processForm(this.parentNode)">Enviar Formulário </button>`
changing submit button type to type="submit" the onclick continues to function,But does not validate the form, swapping it to onsubmit It stops working correctly.

Comment: no, open a new clear page. URL is:

`https://n-czjdyxca7bvlphhhb62gluszu3a2cxnx2a5bcki-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?select1=EMBS& .... 
  =images.jpg`

Comment: @AdsonBatista, add `return false;` in the script...I have modified the code

Comment: Without changes. Want to see the complete in git? Maybe it's easier to understand.

Comment: Not, continue to return the clear page whith Url: 
`https://n-czjdyxca7bvlphhhb62gluszu3a2cxnx2a5bcki-0lu-script‌​.googleusercontent.c‌​om/userCodeAppPanel?‌​select1=EMBS& .... =images.jpg`

Comment: link to git or app script file will help